# Rounding a Square Wave

Tags: speakers, waveform, square

I am using a 555 IC to produce a sound in a small 8 ohm speaker. It works just fine, but the square wave sounds rather harsh. I am wondering if there is a simple way to round out the corners to make it sound better. All the circuits I have found online are rather complex. It seems to me that a simple RC circuit should do the trick, but I have not been able to figure out how to position it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why the modulation tag?

Comment: simple at one 1 tone, wont work over a range

Comment: Modulation tag removed. I thought it was appropriate. My mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple, something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZXRH2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You will have to experiment with the values of R1 and C1, their optimum will depend on the frequency you're making with the NE555.

This will make the signal less loud

Comment: Great, I'll work with that!